# Downloading files from multiple websites.

Tags: python, web, download

This is my first Python project so it is very basic and rudimentary.
I often have to clean off viruses for friends and the free programs that I use are updated often. Instead of manually downloading each program, I was trying to create a simple way to automate the process. Since I am also trying to learn python I thought it would be a good opportunity to practice.

Questions:

I have to find the .exe file with some of the links. I can find the correct URL, but I get an error when it tries to download.

Is there a way to add all of the links into a list, and then create a function to go through the list and run the function on each url? I've Google'd quite a bit and I just cannot seem to make it work. Maybe I am not thinking in the right direction?

```
import urllib, urllib2, re, os
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

# Website List
sas = 'http://cdn.superantispyware.com/SUPERAntiSpyware.exe'
tds = 'http://support.kaspersky.com/downloads/utils/tdsskiller.exe'
mbam = 'http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/malwarebytes-anti-malware/dl/7/?1'
tr = 'http://www.simplysup.com/tremover/download.html'
urllist = [sas, tr, tds, tr]
urrllist2 = []

# Find exe files to download

match = re.compile('\.exe')
data = urllib2.urlopen(urllist)
page = BeautifulSoup(data)

# Check links
#def findexe():
for link in page.findAll('a'):
    try:
        href = link['href']
        if re.search(match, href):
            urllist2.append(href)

    except KeyError:
        pass

os.chdir(r"C:\_VirusFixes")
urllib.urlretrieve(urllist2, os.path.basename(urllist2))
```

As you can see, I have left the function commented out as I cannot get it to work correctly.

Should I abandon the list and just download them individually? I was trying to be efficient.

Any suggestions or if you could point me in the right direction, it would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [mikez302's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13389982/464744), here's a slightly more readable way to write your code:

```
import os
import re
import urllib
import urllib2

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

websites = [
    'http://cdn.superantispyware.com/SUPERAntiSpyware.exe'
    'http://support.kaspersky.com/downloads/utils/tdsskiller.exe'
    'http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/malwarebytes-anti-malware/dl/7/?1'
    'http://www.simplysup.com/tremover/download.html'
]

download_links = []

for url in websites:
    connection = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(connection)
    connection.close()

    for link in soup.findAll('a', {href: re.compile(r'\.exe$')}):
        download_links.append(link['href'])

for url in download_links:
    urllib.urlretrieve(url, r'C:\_VirusFixes', os.path.basename(url))
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. I think I see how I was missing the loops now. Unfortunately, it still isn't working for me. It is still having trouble with the URLs. I will keep troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

`urllib2.urlopen` is a function for accessing a single URL. If you want to access multiple ones, you should loop over the list. You should do something like this:

```
for url in urllist:
    data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    page = BeautifulSoup(data)

    # Check links
    for link in page.findAll('a'):
        try:
            href = link['href']
            if re.search(match, href):
                urllist2.append(href)

        except KeyError:
            pass

    os.chdir(r"C:\_VirusFixes")
    urllib.urlretrieve(urllist2, os.path.basename(urllist2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above didn't work for me, in my case it was because the pages assemble their links through a script instead of including it in the code. When I ran into that problem I used the following code which is just a scraper:

```
import os
import re
import urllib
import urllib2

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = ''

connection = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(connection) #Everything the same up to here 
regex = '(.+?).zip'       #Here we insert the pattern we are looking for
pattern = re.compile(regex)
link = re.findall(pattern,str(soup)) #This finds all the .zip (.exe) in the text
x=0
for i in link:
    link[x]=i.split(' ')[len(i.split(' '))-1] 
# When it finds all the .zip, it usually comes back with a lot of undesirable 
# text, luckily the file name is almost always separated by a space from the 
# rest of the text which is why we do the split
    x+=1  

os.chdir("F:\Documents")
# This is the filepath where I want to save everything I download

for i in link:
    urllib.urlretrieve(url,filename=i+".zip") # Remember that the text we found doesn't include the .zip (or .exe in your case) so we want to reestablish that.
```

This is not as efficient as the codes in the previous answers but it will work for most almost any site.